# Appropriate event architecture for producing an event graph of a company's microservices automation?

Tags: apache-kafka, masstransit, solace

Hello we are trying to determine the best or appropriate architecture for tracking events as they occur between microservices. We know loose coupling begins this process for good microservice design. The use case is to literally query how a company's automation is taking place in real time or historically. There are many products such as Kafka, Solace, MassTransit (mediator, riders, message queues, sagas, routing slips).

Just basic advise at this point. We have to implement saga and routing slip patterns to satisfy our business model.

Comment: An additional note we see the use of DAGs (Directed Acrylic Graph) as a means of illustrating event driven mappings.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend starting by taking a look at the Open Telemetry (OTel). It's a CNCF project, so not tied to specific product, and their goal is to provide a level of observability across your architecture, including the ability of tracing across distributed apps (whether they are sync or async).

I will warn that there is currently a SIG focusing on defining the messaging semantics so this isn't a fully baked solution at this point. You can find more info on that SIG [here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/oteps/blob/main/text/trace/0173-messaging-semantic-conventions.md). They are working to replace the [existing experimental messaging semantic conventions](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/trace/semantic_conventions/messaging.md) with a stable document as things go GA.

That said, you'd probably want to start with instrumenting your apps/microservices and OTel has a number of auto-instrumentation libraries for different APIs & languages in  various [OTel repos](https://github.com/orgs/open-telemetry/repositories). For example, the repo for the Java agent with a number of auto-instrumentation implementations (including JMS) can be found here: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation. The idea of the auto-instrumentation is that it doesn't require app code changes so as things evolve it should be easy for you to evolve with it, which is obviously ideal since the messaging semantics are still in work.

Comment: Thanks so much that's very exciting that its cross architecture and supported by CNCF!

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the Open Telemetry comment above. As far as what is currently used most widely (by any tech or framework involved) in microservices is its predecessor Open Tracing (Open Telemetry is backward compatible to Open Tracing and/as OpenTracing is also CNCF). If interested we have created a microservices workshop that uses tracing across both Rest and messaging (specifically JMS) so you can see working examples. You can view these traces in Jaeger UI and such.  In the same workshop we show "unified observability" where we show metrics, logging, and tracing all within the same Grafana console.  This is really handy as you can, eg, see metrics and/or get a metrics alarm/alert, drill down to its corresponding log entries, and then click/drill down directly from a log entry to its trace (and vice-versa).  Full disclosure, I am from Oracle, and so we also show the ability to trace from the OpenTracing/Kubernetes layer, down into the database thus showing the "3 pillars of observability" across both app and data tiers ...but you don't need the database to do any of the other tracing, etc. shown. The workshop is here:https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/dbpm/r/livelabs/view-workshop?p180_id=637  and the src is here: https://github.com/oracle/microservices-datadriven . I'm definitely interested if you'd like to see add anything added or have any questions, etc.  We'll be adding more OpenTelemetry to it as its adoption grows.